# How can I make a dynamic, no redirect login page?

Tags: html, authentication, server-side

I want to build a login page that is static. 
What I mean by that is after I press "log-in", If my entry
detaild are wring' I want to see it immediately, without re-directions.
e.g. Google's login page or even Stackoverflow's.
How can I do such a thing? In what programming language? Is it supposed to be a server-side one or client?

Comment: It sounds like the overall technology you're looking for is "AJAX", whereby the client-side JavaScript code can communicate with the server without reloading the page.  Any web development technology stack will support this.  You are encouraged to choose any web development technology/language/framework/etc. you like and start with some introductory tutorials, to include using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want result like wrong credentials without redirection , you can use AJAX call for your logic page 
AJAX is Asynchronous JavaScript and XML , which give call to backend or server without reloading page and get result or data

following is short code example of ajax , in login.php you have to write backend code for database connection and login logic

```js
function submitForm() {  
  var data = $("#login-form").serialize();    
  $.ajax({    
   type : 'POST',
   url  : 'login.php',
   data : data,
   beforeSend: function(){ 
    $("#error").fadeOut();
   },
   success : function(response){      
    if(response=="ok")
    {         
     //do redirection 
    } 
    else 
    { 
     $("#error").html(response);
    }
   }
  });
  return false;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sample Login</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <form class="form-login" method="post" id="login-form">
  <h2 class="form-login-heading">User Log In Form</h2><hr />
  <div id="error"></div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="email"  placeholder="Email address" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
   
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button" onclick="submitForm()"> Sign In</button> 
  </div> 
 </form>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be useful to give some example code to show the idea :)